# How to download a file from my media root folder to my phone or computer

Tags: django

Anytime i click on the download link of the mp3 files or images, instead of them starting to download but they just start to preview on the browser. I want when i click on the url "http://localhost:8000/s/download_rdr/1/" and the file "http://localhost:8000/s/media/music.mp3" starts downloading but all it does is to start playing in the browser.

**My views.py**

```py
class DownloadRdr(TemplateView):
       
    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
         
        item = Item.objects.get(id=pk) 
           
        #Return an mp3
        return redirect('http://localhost:8000/s/media/music.mp3')
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, here is a full code:

```
class DownloadRdr(TemplateView):
   
   def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
      if request.user.is_authenticated:
        item = Item.objects.get(id=pk) 
        #order data check
        orderDataCheck = OrderData.objects.filter(item=item, user=request.user)
        orderDataCheck_count = orderDataCheck.count()
        if orderDataCheck_count > 0:
         #Return an mp3
         image_buffer = open(item.upload_file.path, "rb").read()
         response = HttpResponse(image_buffer)
         response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(item.upload_file.path)
         return response
           
         #return redirect(item.upload_file.url)
        else :
           return HttpResponse('<h4>Error, You do not have access to this product!</h4>')
      else:
         return redirect('accounts:login_page')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FileResponse` as docs said: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects

```py
from django.http import FileResponse

def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    response = FileResponse(open(YOUR_FILE_PATH, 'rb'), as_attachment=True)
    return response
```